# Why is QThread deleteLater still required if I am not using a pointer object of QThread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    Two objTwo;

    QThread objQThread;

    Controller();

public slots:
    void mySlot(){}
};

Controller::Controller()
{
    objTwo.moveToThread( &objQThread );

    connect( &objTwo, &Two::emitThisSignal, this, &Controller::mySlot );
    connect( &objQThread, &QThread::finished, &objQThread, &QThread::deleteLater );

    objQThread.start();
}
```

Here the QThread's object is not a pointer, so will it still be required to use `deleteLater` here?
Is it appropriate to use class objects there instead of pointers?

I thought deletion can be prevented that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here the QThread's object is not a pointer, so will it still be required to use `deleteLater` here?

No.

> Is it appropriate to use class objects there instead of pointers?

Totally, don't use pointers if you don't need to.

> I thought deletion can be prevented that way.

*Manual deletion* can be prevented this way, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use deleteLater at all because there is QScopedPointer. Example [here](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/QThread-with-moveToThread_console.git).